# AEM Standalone Component Library Site

Tags: aem

I haven't used AEM in about 4 years so I'm familiar but not intimately so with the updated versions of the CMS. Right now, I'm doing research into whether or not this is even possible.

Ideally, what I'd like to create is a standalone site of all the different AEM components that our development team has created over time. There are about 20 components that I'd like to display in a list similar to the [Phillips Component Library](https://www.philips.co.uk/componentlibrary/home.html). This would be used as a reference guide for our UX, creatives, and content authors.

In order to minimize rework from our development team, and keep this site in sync with current component states, I want to be able to pull the component code directly from what's in AEM and display on this new standalone site. However, I'm not sure what that looks like technically. Is there a "component API" where we can pull that code out of AEM and then display in this standalone site?

I know this will probably require something custom built - I'm ok with that - but I'm unsure of where to start with the architecture.

Comment: Adobe is promoting their Core Components, it is like a library of common components but using standards and are well tested since they have been open-sourced. Take a look of them here: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/

Comment: i think @addam wants to recreate a component library - something similar to the philips one. AFAIK, I don't think there are component API's to achieve this. It has to be a custom solution. The current components as-is can be used in a template and you can build a custom component to get the tabbed view(details, change log, etc) as in the philips site. If the clientlibs for your site are not loaded at a component level, organizing the clientlibs for the component library will probably require some refactoring.